# How to create a Mirrored Volume in Windows 8.1 - mirror option missing

Tags: windows-8.1, raid

I am trying to create a mirrored volume (RAID-1) in Windows 8.1 (standard edition, not Pro). This is a new Windows 8.1 installation.

I have two 500GB drives attached to SATA ports, neither of which contains the boot partition (it's on a separate SSD).

One of the 500GB drives has data that I want to keep (mirror).  The other drive is empty.

I converted both drives to Dynamic Disk.

However, when I right-click on the partition that contains data, there is no option to mirror.  The option is simply not present on the menu.

I was following [these instructions](http://www.avoiderrors.net/set-mirror-arrey-windows-81/).

Is this a limitation of the standard version of Windows 8.1 or am I missing something?

I also tried to use the Storage Spaces tool to create a storage space, but the only drive it even offers me is an external USB drive. None of my internal drives

Here's a [screenshot](http://snag.gy/t5BpY.jpg) of my Disk Management screen.
Here's a [screenshot](http://snag.gy/CSUDo.jpg) of the popup menu when right-clicking the first drive.
Here's a [screenshot](http://snag.gy/tbuNH.jpg) of Storage Spaces. As you can see, it won't display any drives except my USB drive to add to Storage Spaces.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Are you trying to implement a software or hardware RAID solution?

Comment: Software RAID using Windows "Mirror" option.  My MB doesn't support hardware RAID.

Comment: @RyanGriggs Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Nope! I did not.